# Find a process ID by name

Tags: ruby, unix

How can I find a pid by name or full command line in Ruby, without calling an external executable?

I am sending SIGUSR2 to a process whose command line contained `ruby job.rb`. I would like to do the following without the call to `pgrep`:

```
uid = Process.uid
pid = `pgrep -f "ruby job.rb" -u #{uid}`.split("\n").first.to_i
Process.kill "USR2", pid
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but if we're already making an external system call, we can also kill the process right there. E.g. `\`pgrep -f 'some job' | xargs kill\``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick google search came up with [sys_proctable](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable), which should let you do this in a portable way.

Disclaimer: I don't use Ruby, can't confirm if this works.

Answer (score 9):

How to do this depends on your operating system.  Assuming Linux, you can manually crawl the /proc filesystem and look for the right command line.  However, this is the same thing that pgrep is doing, and will actually make the program *less* portable.

Something like this might work.

```
def get_pid(cmd)
  Dir['/proc/[0-9]*/cmdline'].each do|p|
    if File.read(p) == cmd
      Process.kill( "USR2", p.split('/')[1] )
    end
  end
end
```

Just be careful poking around in /proc.

Comment: Speaking of *less portable* - this does not work on Solaris. You are presuming that you are running on Linux here.

Comment: Yes, I did say "assuming Linux."

Comment: +1 Accepted another answer, but I like this too. A reminder of just how much you can do on Linux in any language with just the file-system

Answer (score 1):

Debian based systems find pid with pidof command.

Some kill proccess function with ruby:

```
def killPid(cmd)
   pid=exec("pidof #{cmd}")
   Process.kill "USR2", pid
end
```

Comment: if you run multiple instances of the same command with different params pidof won't help

Comment: This may be dangerous, depending on where the parameter is coming from. You're interpolating a string into a command. The String may well be `test; rm -rf /var/www/`. [exec](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) can take things like this in multiple arguments, so `exec('pidof', cmd)` would be much safer.